# Train and Test accuracy separately in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

This is my model:

```
def evaluate_model(X_train, y_train,X_test,y_test):

  verbose=1
  epochs=50
  batch_size = 32
  
  n_outputs = 1
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=6, activation='relu', input_shape=(25,1)))
  model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=6, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dropout(0.3))
  model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
  model.add(Flatten())
  model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='sigmoid'))
  model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
  # fit network
  model.fit(X_train, y_train,epochs=50, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1)
      # evaluate model
  _, accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1)
  return accuracy
  
# summarize scores
def summarize_results(scores):
    print(scores)
    m, s = mean(scores), std(scores)
    print('Accuracy: %.3f%% (+/-%.3f)' % (m, s))
 
# run an experiment
def run_experiment(repeats=5):

    # repeat experiment
    scores = list()
    for r in range(repeats):
        score = evaluate_model(X_train, y_train,X_test,y_test)
        score = score * 100.0
        print('>#%d: %.3f' % (r+1, score))
        scores.append(score)
    # summarize results
    summarize_results(scores)

# run the experiment
run_experiment()
```

How do I get the train and test accuracy separately? Right now I am only getting test accuracy with `model.evaluate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What accuracy you get depends on the arguments you use with `model.evaluate()`; if you replace `X_test` and `y_test` with `X_train` and `y_train`, respectively, you will get the training accuracy. So, to get both, you should modify the last lines of your `evaluate_model` function as:

```
_, train_accuracy = model.evaluate(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1)
_, test_accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1)
return train_accuracy, test_accuracy
```

Comment: In model.fit if I do verbose=1..what accuracy is it showing there? train or test?

Comment: @ubuntu_noob They correspond training loss and accuracy, otherwise it will show validation_loss etc.

Comment: @ubuntu_noob since you have not provided a validation set in `model.fit`, it will show only the training loss & accuracy; had you provided an additional argument `validation_data=(X_test, y_test)`, it would show both training and test loss & accuracy. See the [documentation](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/#fit-method).

Comment: @desertnaut the test accuracy from model.evaluate and if we put validation_data=(X_test, y_test) and verbose=1 in model.fit...are both the test accuracy the same thing? As in both are doing the same role?

Comment: @ubuntu_noob in principle yes; but there may be some discrepancies due to how exactly Keras calculates the accuracy during training. Such cases have generated a rather long number of relevant questions here...

Comment: @desertnaut When we do validation_data=(X_test, y_test)..isnt that the validation accuracy we get?

Comment: @ubuntu_noob technically yes, but this is actually a matter of what dataset you use as an argument; do you actually have a separate *validation* set which you don't show here? If you don't, and you actually use your *test* data there, then you get the "test" accuracy.